# Codeigniter a href redirecting to localhost WAMP Server

Tags: codeigniter, href

I'm new in CodeIgniter and trying to create a simple link on Homepage but it is redirecting to localhost on WAMP Server, here is my code

**autoload.php** in config folder

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('html', 'url');
```

**config.php** in config folder

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/OTI-CI';
```

**routes.php** in config folder

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

here is my controller: **site.php**

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->home();
    }

    public function home() {
        $this->load->view("header");
        $this->load->view("content_home");
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }
}
```

here is my **.htaccess** file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /OTI-CI/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]    

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

here is my view of header include a link like

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/home">Home</a>
```

is there anything I'm missing about it?

Comment: Which version of CodeIgniter v2.x or v3.x?

Comment: So `<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/home">Home</a>` would render  `<a href="http://localhost:8080/OTI-CIsite/home">Home</a>` (note the missing slash) ? What do you see in your browser?

Comment: 3.0.1 is the version @Bora

Comment: URL i'm getting is `http://localhost:8080/OTI-CI/site/home` @jtheman

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter `3.x` version, you should capitalize **Controllers, Libraries and Models** name. Like that `Site.php`

#### Wrong:

```
/application/controllers/site.php
```

#### Right:

```
/application/controllers/Site.php
```

Comment: I change the Controller name from `site.php` to `Site.php`, also update `routes.php` with `Site` and at the end use capital S in `<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Site/home">Home</a>` but still it can't fix my issue, i'm redirecting to localhost with following URL `http://localhost:8080/OTI-CI/Site/home`

Comment: this works for me, by adding `index.php`
`<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/site/home">Home</a>`